# Insert into a model with two foreign keys on a post save signal

Tags: django

I do not know how to do the following thing:
I have three models:

```
#models

class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Sections = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Employee_Users = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                null=True,blank=True)
    @receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
    def create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(Students_Enrollment_Records=instance.Student_Users,
                                                   Subject_Section_Teacher = SubjectSectionTeacher.Employee_Users)
```

I just want that when the admin update the student enrollment record and must be added automatically in StudentsEnrolledSubject

**UPDATE**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
def create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Courses=instance.Courses, Sections=instance.Section)
    if created:
        StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
            # This should be the instance not instance.Student_Users
            Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
            # The below is also not an instance of SubjectSectionTeacher
            Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.Employee_Users)
```

then i received this error

```
AttributeError at /admin/Homepage/studentsenrollmentrecord/add/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'Employee_Users'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are not sending the teacher information properly. Here I am assuming a teacher can be found from `Courses` and `Sections` information of the `StudentsEnrollmentRecord`, because its the only information common with `SubjectSectionTeacher` model fields.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
def create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Courses=instance.Courses, Sections=instance.Sections)
    if teachers.exists() and created:
             StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(Students_Enrollment_Records=instance.Student_Users,
                                               Subject_Section_Teacher = teachers.first())
```

---

### Update

Change from:

```
if created:
    StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
        # This should be the instance not instance.Student_Users
        Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
        # The below is also not an instance of SubjectSectionTeacher
        Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.Employee_Users)
```

To:

```
 if created and teachers.exists():  # Checks if teachers exists for that section and course.
     StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
         Students_Enrollment_Records=instance.Student_Users,
         Subject_Section_Teacher = teachers.first()
     )
```

Comment: Good catch sir , but the StudentsEnrolledSubject dont receive data from StudentsEnrollmentRecord and SubjectSectionTeacher

Comment: then what should I do sir?

Comment: yes and i receive this error """""StudentsEnrolledSubject.Subject_Section_Teacher" must be a "SubjectSectionTeacher" instance."""

Comment: Thats not suppose to happen. Because I am getting `SubjectSectionTeacher` instance from teachers variable (`teachers.first()`)

Comment: Maybe you dont have data of SubjectSectionTeacher , i update my question sir

Comment: @kaito instead of `Subject_Section_Teacher=teachers.Employee_Users` use `Subject_Section_Teacher = teachers.first()`

Comment: Nice one sir :)

Answer (score 1):

There's an indentation error in your code.

```py
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(models.Model):
    Student_Users = models.ForeignKey(StudentProfile, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Sections = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Employee_Users = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
def create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
            # This should be the instance not instance.Student_Users
            Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
            # The below is also not an instance of SubjectSectionTeacher
            Subject_Section_Teacher=SubjectSectionTeacher.Employee_Users)
```

Also, if the code is not working check the python console for errors(Add them to your question if there are any).

Comment: thank you for your answer , i receive this error """" Cannot assign "<StudentProfile: test   test test>": "StudentsEnrolledSubject.Students_Enrollment_Records" must be a "StudentsEnrollmentRecord" instance. """"

Comment: Check the updated answer. Also, how are you thinking of getting an instance of `SubjectSectionTeacher` inside the `post_save` signal?